# django: my application seems to be leaking; how to diangose?

Tags: django, memory-leaks, wsgi

I have a django application deployed using mod_wsgi. The processes are growing to the point, where they are killed by the OS. How can I diagnose, what is causing to grow?

Answer (score 0):

[Dozer](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19420) may be of use to you, its WSGI middleware that will give you object counts and possibly yield some useful results for you.

You could also simplify things by using [wsgiref](http://docs.python.org/library/wsgiref.html) to run just your application and narrow down if the problem is in the Python code, the CPython code, or Apache. It's a little banging-the-rocks-togetherish but when in doubt reduce the variables of your problem and it'll make the problems stand out.

Comment: I don't work in this company anymore ;-) But we used Dozer at the time and we still couldn't detect the leak.